# Proof of convergence of sequence of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

I came across the following exercise. Say we have a sequence of events $E_i$ in some probability space. We know $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(E_i) = 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_i \cap E^c_{i+1}) < \infty$

The exercise is to show that $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup E_i) = 0$

By Borel Cantelli we know that $P(\lim \sup E_i \cap E^c_{i+1}) = 0$ but I can't figure out the algebraic manipulation to get to what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can realize that $\bigcup_{k\geq n} E_k = E_n\cup\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_{k+1}\setminus E_k$. Then, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_k\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(E_n\cup\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_{k+1}\setminus E_k\right)\\
&\leq \mathbb{P}(E_n)+\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_{k+1}\setminus E_k\right)
\end{align*}
By Borel-Cantelli, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_{k+1}\setminus E_k) = 0$, and therefore
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_k\right) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(E_n)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_{k+1}\setminus E_k\right) = 0
\end{align*}
so $\mathbb{P}(\limsup E_n) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how does B.C. theorem imply limn→∞P(⋃k≥n Ek+1∖Ek)=0 doesn't it just imply that P(⋂⋃k≥n Ek+1∖Ek)=0?

Comment: Borel Cantelli implies that P(⋂⋃k≥n Ek+1∖Ek)=0, and this fact implies limn→∞P(⋃k≥n Ek+1∖Ek)=0 (you only have to use the continuity of the probability measure).